# Android - Change colors dynamically for a single list item in a listview

Tags: android

I want to change colors dynamically for a single list item in a listview. Is this possible?

Below is my code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
   View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
   if(menus[position] == "New")
     {
       text.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
       text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
     }   
     return view;
  }
```

Now the color is blue. I want to change this to red from blue and vice versa.How to do this? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

How about use "handler", send a delayed message to handler, and change the color while handle receive the message.